# Boxplot add line to a single box

Tags: r, boxplot

I am plotting the local clustering (`transitivity` with `type = c('local')` argument) of some graphs in a `boxplot`.

[image: plot]

I calculated the `global` transitivity of these graphs and I want to represent it as an additional line of the plot as wide as each box.

```
 df <- data.frame(values = c(full_trans, clus_trans), vars = rep(c("Full","Clustering"), times=c(20,20)))
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))
 boxplot(values~vars, data=df, ylim=c(0:1), yaxt='n', boxwex=0.5)
```

I tried `abline`, but it draws a line through all the plot which doesn't look how I wanted.

Comment: Try to play with `segments`. Consider that each level should be a unit of the abscissa (so Clustering should have abscissa equal to 1, Full equal to 2).

Comment: This also might help: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/109786.html I'd go with the `segments` version in [@koekenbakker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2516066/koekenbakker)'s answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create data:

```
d = data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10))
```

Plot boxplots of a defined width:

```
my_width = 0.5
boxplot(d, boxwex=my_width)
```

Add lines for global transmissivity using another boxplot (green)

```
global_tr = 0.3
extra_d = data.frame(a=global_tr,b=global_tr)
boxplot(x = extra_d, at = c(1,2), add=T,col=3,  boxwex=my_width, border=3)
```

... or using segments (red)

```
x = 1:2
segments(x0=x-0.5*my_width, x1=x+0.5*my_width,y0=0.3, y1=0.3, col=2)
```

[image: boxplot with extra line]